# UIWebView. Badaccess when reloading in viewDidDisappear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I am trying to reload content from local file of UIWebView in viewDidDisappear of UIViewController. Badaccess is caught. But if I write the same code in viewWillDisappear, it works.
What might be the reason?
Once I've heard that UIWebView can't reload its content when it is not visible (not sure about it).

My code (hope it'll be enough):

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    ExtendedWebView * webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ExtendedWebView * webView;
@end
```

---

```
//WebViewController implementation
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    WebViewCachingSingleton * webViewSingleton = [WebViewCachingSingleton sharedService];
        ExtendedWebView * newWebView = [webViewSingleton getAvailableWebViewResource];//here I get ExtendedWebView. it works =)
    newWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
    newWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:newWebView];
    self.webView = newWebView;
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[WebViewCachingSingleton sharedService] makeWebViewUnused:self.webView];
}
```

---

```
//WebViewCachingSingleton:
- (void) makeWebViewUnused : (ExtendedWebView *) aWebView
{
    aWebView.isFree = YES;
    [aWebView reload];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because viewDidDisappear is called when the view is disappeared, so all the subviews are released. The viewWillDisappear is called just before releasing all the objects associated with that view.

So you are trying to call the reload method of a UIWebView that has been already released. That is basically the reason why it crashes.

Hope it helps

Comment: My WebView(ExtendedWebView, see the code) is referenced from another singleton object, so it is not deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

The reload can be performed even if not displayed.

I tried to make an example of code to put in your state and have not had any problems.
Try to debug and enable NSZombieEnabled to see what actually happens to your application.
Try to post on any piece of code that might help us give you more details.